# Return a if a>0 else return 0

Tags: python, math, python-3.6

I am writing a python program with a lot and complicated math calculations.In my code i have many cases where i want to get a number if it is greater than 0 or return 0 if it isn't.

I know i can do this:

```
a if a > 0 else 0
```

or even

```
a if a >= 0 else 0
```

What i am looking for is a function in `math` library, or in basic python3.6 library which will do the job in a more elegant way, so i don't have to include any one line if statements inside my code like that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about using return max(a, 0)?

Comment: Wikipedia also recommends max(a, 0): [Wikipedia: Positive and negative parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts)

Comment: @ItaiDagan As short as this recommendation is, you should post it as an answer!